# Error on Cloud 9 While trying to install and run MEAN stack

Tags: gruntjs, bower, mean-stack, cloud9-ide

I have installed the mean stack with bower and grunt on cloud 9 server but every time I try to run:

```
gwenf1@basejump_voting:~/workspace $ grunt serve
```

I get the follwing errors:

```
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task

Running "env:all" (env) task

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

Running "injector:scripts" (injector) task
Missing option `template`, using `dest` as template instead
Injecting js files (13 files)

Running "injector:css" (injector) task
Missing option `template`, using `dest` as template instead
Injecting css files (5 files)

Running "wiredep:target" (wiredep) task
client/index.html modified.
Loading "autoprefixer.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'caniuse-db/features-json/transforms2d'
Warning: Task "autoprefixer" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Execution Time (2015-08-31 04:28:36 UTC)
loading tasks      173ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 18%
serve               15ms  ▇▇ 2%
clean:server        26ms  ▇▇▇ 3%
env:all             12ms  ▇▇ 1%
concurrent:server   13ms  ▇▇ 1%
injector:scripts   103ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 11%
injector:css        17ms  ▇▇ 2%
wiredep:target     613ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 63%
Total 976ms

gwenf1@basejump_voting:~/workspace $ grunt serve
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task

Running "env:all" (env) task

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

Running "injector:scripts" (injector) task
Missing option `template`, using `dest` as template instead
Injecting js files (13 files)

Running "injector:css" (injector) task
Missing option `template`, using `dest` as template instead
Injecting css files (5 files)

Running "wiredep:target" (wiredep) task
Loading "autoprefixer.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'caniuse-db/features-json/transforms2d'
Warning: Task "autoprefixer" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I have tried installing different versions of everything and deleting the workspace and starting over.

Comment: In your output: 
`>> Error: Cannot find module 'caniuse-db/features-json/transforms2d'` can you install the missing module and try again?

Comment: @Mutahhir Yes, I tried running 'bower install && npm install' again but to no avail. I also ran 'grunt serve --force' but I the app still wouldn't run

Comment: @Mutahhir I can't seem to figure out why it says I am missing a module

Comment: Force won't work as long as there's a problem with missing modules. You'll need to find where the module 'caniuse-db' is being referenced within your code and either install it `npm install --save caniuse-db` or remove the reference